# CsvHelper rounding a double to two places in maps

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

For mapping classes I have this.

```
public sealed class MyMap : ClassMap<MyBase>
{
    public MyMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.EventDate).Index(1);
        Map(m => Math.Round(m.Price,2)).Index(2);
    }
}
```

Is there a way that will work as this errors out when rounding. I know you can use custom converters but that seems like over kill just to truncate input to two decimal places.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: CS1061 'double' does not contain a definition for 'Index' and no accessible extension method 'Index' accepting a first argument of type 'double' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
public sealed class MyMap : ClassMap<MyBase>
{
    public MyMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.EventDate).Index(1);
        Map(m => m.Price).Index(2).Convert(row => Math.Round(row.Row.GetField<decimal>("Price"),2));
    }
}
```

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: 'No members were found in expression '{expression}'.'

Comment: And its rounding a double to two decimal places.

Comment: Ended up with this. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.             Map(m => m.Price).Convert(row =>
            {
                var fieldVal = row.Row.GetField<double>(2);
                return Math.Round(fieldVal,2);
            });